# How can I align horizontally matrices of different dimensions?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, matrices

I'm wondering how can I align two different matrices horizontally. They are:

[-1 0 +1]

And:

[-1 0 +1].T

This is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\top
\end{equation}
```

And this is how the matrices appear, which is expected:

[image]

However, I would left aligned.
I tried to use `\begin{align}` and `\begin{array}`, but I didn't succeed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a good idea to use two consecutive display math environments with nothing in between (because the spacing will be wrong).

Using `align`, the alignment characters can go before the beginning of the `bmatrix` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \\
&\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\top
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]